# How to make responsive HTML markup?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend

I know about media queries in CSS. But what if need different HTML markups for desktop and mobile version (different structure of containers)? What is the best practice there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to use frameworks like Twitter Bootstrap or Foundation. Check this article :

http://www.designyourway.net/blog/resources/27-of-the-best-css-and-html-frameworks-available-to-download/

Comment: I'm already using Bootsrap. Suppose, I have an HTML block, located in content container in desktop version. But in the mobile version this block should be displayed in the header container near the site logo. The best solution I found is to duplicate this block in the header and content containers, and then add to one of them classes `.visible-phone .hidden-desktop` and for second one - `.visible-desktop .hidden-phone`. Is it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

For responsive HTML we can achieve in following ways

```
1.instead of pixel use %
2.media queries
3.jquery mobile  http://jquerymobile.com/
```